# how to test a redux action that dispatch other action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am using jest + react testing library

And as the title describes, what I am trying to test is that the testAction dispatch the secondTestAction, but I am getting an error saying the secondTestAction didnt dispatched which cant be true because the massage on the function is getting printed.

anyone has a clue how can I make this test working?

the action

```js
export const testAction = () => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(secondTestAction());
};
export const secondTestAction = () => {
    console.log('second action have been dispatched');
};
```

the test

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import * as userActions from '../../../redux/actions/userActions';
import store from '../../../redux/store';

const secondTestActionSpy = jest.spyOn(userActions, 'secondTestAction');

test('should dispatch secondTestActions ', async () => {
    await store.dispatch(userActions.testAction());
    expect(secondTestActionSpy.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
});
```

the error

```js
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality
Expected: 1
Received: 0
expect(secondTestActionSpy.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You see, you are importing all your actions(those are `export`'ed) into test. Then you locally - only in the test - replace one of imported action with spy wrapper. But actions in `userActions.js` does not go to your test file, one function just calls another one, directly, just that version that is declared, rather a wrapped-with-a-spy version.

What can you do? If you want to follow approach with "test that action has been called" you can use [`redux-mock-store`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-mock-store):

```
import { testAction, secondAction } from '../../../redux/actions/userActions';

test('should dispatch secondTestActions ', async () => {
    mockedStore.dispatch(userActions.testAction());
    expect(mockedStore.getActions()).toContainEqual(secondAction());
});
```

so how to make this `mockedStore`? Just use default export from `redux-mock-store`:

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)(constantStoreData);
```

Since `redux-mock-store` does not process actions through reducers, it does not actually require you to rely on reducers. So neither `../store` is needed here.

But this way you just test what actions are called(and in what order - if you use `expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(...` instead of `expect(store.getActions()).toContainEqual(...`).

To my opinion, much easier and more reliable to test store as a whole - with both actions and reducers, mocking just external-world interaction(like requests to server, operations with localstorage etc). Then tests would dispatch some action and ensure final state is as expected:

```
it('sets loading once request started', () => {
  const realStore = createStore(userReducer, someInitialState);
  realStore.dispatch(loadUsersAction(someArgument));
  expect(realStore.getState().isLoading).toEqual(true);
});

it('unsets loading once loading users failed', async () => {
  // mock specific request to fail
  const realStore = createStore(userReducer, someInitialState);
  realStore.dispatch(loadUsersAction(someArgument));
  await undefined; // let's skip Promises queue once; does nothing special, await 42 would work the same;
  expect(realStore.getState().isLoading).toEqual(false);
});
```